# why can't I validate user input in this way? Python

Tags: validation, python-2.7, range

I was trying to validate a user input to see if it is within the range of 1 to 500.
The following is the code that i have come up with:

```
while teamScore not in range (1,501):
    print "The score is not in the valid range!"
    teamScore=raw_input("Please enter the team score (1-500): ")
```

However, when I run the code, other than stating that 0 and 900 are invalid, it does not accept the correct numbers such as 34, 79, 200.

I would like to still use my while loop, anyone can enlighten me how I should amend my code?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while teamScore not in range (1,501):
    print "The score is not in the valid range!"
    teamScore=int(raw_input("Please enter the team score (1-500): "))
```

raw_input() returns a string, you should convert it into int.

Comment: oh yes, i see it now, no wonder I could do it last time and not this time round! Thank you so much!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string containing user input. Your while loop uses that string and checks if it is in an integer range. Convert the `teamscore` variable to an integer.

```
while teamScore not in range (1,501):
    print "The score is not in the valid range!"
    teamScore=raw_input("Please enter the team score (1-500): ")
    try: 
         teamScore = int(teamScore)
    except ValueError:
         teamScore = 0
```